# Reusable ViewCell with MVVMCross and Xamarin Forms Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross 5.0.6 and Xamarin.Forms. I am trying to create a reusable Xaml template, and inject it into my a main xaml View. But I keep having an "Unhandled exception" error.

```
FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:10. Cannot assign property "Content": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.Object rootElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x000de] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:310 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0023d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:139 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000b1] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:175 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:225 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext) [0x0007a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:125 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x00046] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:76 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x0002f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:56 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:36 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at AmeliMemo.Core.Pages.MemoPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\Users\hamiri\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\...\.Core.Pages.MemoPage.xaml.g.cs:20 
07-26 16:00:47.017 E/mono-rt (13364):   at ..Pages.MemoPage..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users..\visual studio 2017\Projects\..Core\Pages\MemoPage.xaml.cs:11
```

Here is my code:

**MemoPage.xaml**

```
<mvx:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms" 
         x:Class="...Core.Pages.MemoPage"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:...Core.Pages.Items"
         Title="Memo">
    <views:FirstMemoPage/>
```

**MemoPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MemoPage
{
    public MemoPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

**MemoViewModel**

```
public class MemoViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    IMvxNavigationService navigationService;

    public MemoViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

**FirstMemoPage.xaml**

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="...Core.Pages.Items.FirstMemoPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hi!"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

**FirstMemoPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class FirstMemoPage 
{
    public FirstMemoPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a `Cell` directly to the content of a `Page`.

So, either change your **FirstMemoPage.xaml**, to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="...Core.Pages.Items.FirstMemoPage">
        <Label Text="Hi!"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

And change the `FirstMemoPage` class accordingly.

Or use the `Cell` only in a `ListView` or similar containers.

Comment: Thanks alot! that works.. And if i want to bind some variable inside FirstMemoPage, and this variable changes from a view to another. Do u have an Idea how to do that? Thanks alot

Comment: You will have to create and expose your own bindable properties in your control. Google 'reusable Xamarin controls' you'll find some examples!